# scipy 'Minimize the sum of squares of a set of equations'

Tags: python, scipy

I face a problem in scipy 'leastsq' optimisation routine, if i execute the following program it says

```
    raise errors[info][1], errors[info][0]
TypeError: Improper input parameters.
```

and sometimes `index out of range for an array`...

```
from scipy import *
import numpy
from scipy import optimize
from numpy import asarray
from math import *

def func(apar):
  apar = numpy.asarray(apar)
  x = apar[0]
  y = apar[1]
  eqn = abs(x-y)
  return eqn

Init = numpy.asarray([20.0, 10.0])
x = optimize.leastsq(func, Init, full_output=0, col_deriv=0, factor=100, diag=None, warning=True)
print 'optimized parameters: ',x
print '******* The End ******'
```

I don't know what is the problem with my func optimize.leastsq() call, please help me

Comment: Can you format your code please? It will make it easier for people to help you :).

Comment: Your `func()` could simply be written as `def func(apar): return abs(apar[0]-apar[1])`.  There is no need for coercion, as `leastsq` passes Numpy arrays to the minimized function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`leastsq` works with vectors so the residual function, `func`, needs to return a vector of length at least two.  So if you replace `return eqn` with `return [eqn, 0.]`, your example will work.  Running it gives:

```
optimized parameters:  (array([10., 10.]), 2)
```

which is one of the many correct answers for the minimum of the absolute difference.

If you want to minimize a scalar function, `fmin` is the way to go, `optimize.fmin(func, Init)`.

The issue here is that these two functions, although they look the same for a scalars are aimed at different goals.  `leastsq` finds the least squared error, generally from a set of idealized curves, and is just one way of doing a "best fit".  On the other hand `fmin` finds the minimum value of a scalar function.

Obviously yours is a toy example, for which neither of these really makes sense, so which way you go will depend on what your final goal is.

Comment: It looks like you're right.  However, if this is true, this looks like a bug to me.  The minimizer should be able to minimize a simple scalar function, if it can "minimize" a list of numbers…  What do you think?

Comment: @EOL - So I don't get an upvote for the correct answer because you don't like the way scipy works? Tough crowd.  But I agree that it does seem like it should work without this kludge, and it would be an easy thing to correct.

Comment: @tom10 You might be interested in checking my answer… :)

Comment: @tom10 I can see you liked the `fmin()` function I suggested! :)

Comment: @EOL - Yes, your answer is truly wonderful and amazing, that's why I upvoted it. And that you clearly thought it up all on your own without any reference to my answer, surely all the more impressive.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the [least squares docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html), it might be that your function `func` is defined incorrectly. You're assuming that you always receive an array of at least length 2, but the optimize function is insanely vague about the length of the array you will receive. You might try writing to screen whatever `apar` is, to see what you're actually getting.

If you're using something like `ipython` or the python shell, you ought to be getting stack traces that show you exactly which line the error is occurring on, so start there. If you can't figure it out from there, posting the stack trace would probably help us.

Comment: Reading the doc *carefully and thoroughly* is good advice. General minimizers have a long history of having confusing and tricky interfaces. Try writing one some day, and you'll see why.

Comment: he assumes that `apar` has *at least* 2 elements, not exactly two. Which doesn't contradict your point, just a minor correction.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to minimize a simple scalar function (`func()` returns a single value, not a list of values), `scipy.optimize.leastsq()` should be replaced by a call to one of the `fmin` functions (with the appropriate arguments):

```
x = optimize.fmin(func, Init)
```

correctly works!

In fact, `leastsq()` minimizes the sum of squares of a list of values.  It does not appear to work on a (list containing a) single value, as in your example (even though it could, in theory).

Comment: Yes, I am aware that it works with 'optimize.fmin' but i want to try with 'optimize.leastsq'